# Sort order using Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, project-reactor, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am doing a geospatial search using Spring Data Elasticsearch - basically, finding all entities within a given radius based on lat/long coordinates stored in ES (@GeoPointField). Previously we used the transport client and things worked fine. We have recently switched to using the latest Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch (Spring Boot Data ElasticSearch Starter 2.2.0) and have noticed that our sorting no longer is being applied. I.e. the closest locations by distance are no longer at the beginning of the result list. The logic with **QueryBuilder** and **SearchQuery** has not changed, instead, we are now just using **ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate** and returning a **Flux**.

Our logic to get the response now looks something like below.

```
 //TODO this does not sort the results properly based on distance as it previously did using transport client
    public Mono<LocationResultDTO> findLocationsNearby(Location fromLocation, Integer distance, BusinessUnit businessUnit) {

        if (distance == null || distance == 0) {
            distance = defaultDistance;
        }

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(fromLocation.getLatitude(), fromLocation.getLongitude());

        // this is the actual query to find everything from a certain point
        QueryBuilder query = geoDistanceQuery("geoLocationAsString")
                .point(point)
                .distance(distance, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);

        // 1) do not include the input store
        // 2) only use selling locations! - MFD-4765
        // 3) only find stores in the same business unit
        QueryBuilder filter = boolQuery()
                .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("storeNumber", fromLocation.getStoreNumber()))
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("sellingLocation", "Y"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("businessUnit", businessUnit));

        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(query)
                .withFilter(filter)
                .withSort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort("geoLocationAsString", point) // this sorts by distance
                .order(SortOrder.ASC)).build();

        // get the Flux from repository
        Flux<Location> locationFlux = reactiveElasticsearchTemplate.find(searchQuery, Location.class);

        // map to a Mono List - should this preserve order of the stream?
        Mono<List<Location>> locationList = locationFlux.flatMapSequential(location -> Mono.just(location)).collectList();

        // map to our DTO
        return locationList.flatMap(locations -> Mono.just(LocationResultDTO.builder().result(locations).build()));
```

We are fairly new to using reactive idioms and wondering if we are mapping the resulting Flux from the reactive template correctly? Should the resulting Flux from the reactive template maintain sorting order?

Comment: when using the non-reactive rest client - does this work?